# Controlling a CSS animation with JS?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

Let's say I have the following CSS animation:

```
@animation experiencebar {
    from {background:blue;width:0}
    80% {background:blue;width:100%}
    90% {background:yellow;opacity:1}
    to {opacity:0}
}
```

In English, the bar grows from empty to full in blue, then fades to yellow before fading out.

Is there any way to say "style this element as if it were at 50% of the animation"? (In this case, with a blue background and a width of 62.5%)

If so, is there any way to transition this, such as when experience is gained I could make it transition to 70% animated? Going further, could I set the position to 120% to have the animation fill the bar, fade it out, then appear to start a new bar for the next level?

Or is this too far-fetched even for CSS transitions/animations and should be done in JavaScript?

Comment: Kolink, you should check to see if it is possible to mix from and to states with percentages because I haven't seen that before.

Comment: `from` is an alias of `0%` and `to` is an alias of `100%`. They're clearly-defined as such.

Comment: *Well, actually...* you can pause and play CSS animations (not transitions) in JavaScript, by setting [`animation-play-state`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/animation-play-state). It's not the right way to go for precision, though.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no way to directly manipulate the CSS Transition with the way you mentioned. You could just set different classes with different animations, and simply shift through the classes via the `.setAttribute("class","classname")` method. Also, you could manipulate the particular properties in JavaScript, but this would require you to change it back; this is much less elegant than shifting classes.

Answer (score 1):

Animations cannot be accessed from javascript for now but I think there is a walk through for this problem. Calculate and use transitions fully. You can have different classes with different transition properties and in javascript you can apply the class you want . This method will display your required animation from javascript.

Comment: Oh, we practically wrote the same answer. +1.

Comment: Because its the best answer we can think of :) Its just the timing Bagavatu. +1